# Convert <String, Dynamic) to the object format in Dart

Tags: dart

I've those objects:

```
class ServerResponse {
  bool successfully;
  int count;
  String? errorMsg;
  String? errorCode;
  Map<String, dynamic>? data;
  ServerResponse(
      {required this.successfully,
      required this.count,
      this.errorMsg,
      this.errorCode,
      this.data});
}
import 'dart:convert';
import './models.dart';

/ --------------------------------
class MyClass {

  String organisationId;
  String regionCode;
  Culture defaultCulture;

  MyClass({
    required this.organisationId,
    required this.regionCode,
    required this.defaultCulture,
  });
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'organisationId': organisationId,
      'regionCode': regionCode,
      'default culture': defaultCulture
    };
  }

  factory MyClass.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return AppValidated(
        organisationId: map['organisationId'],
        regionCode: map['regionCode'],
        defaultCulture: map['defaultCulture']);
  }
  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());
  factory MyClass.fromJson(String source) =>
      MyClass.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}
```

And on my code, I've this...

```
ServerResponse rd = response.data;
MyClass mc = rd.data;
```

However, MyClass mc = rd.data is throwing me a *A value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'MyClass'*

How can I handle it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your class provides a `fromMap` factory. Try this:

```dart
MyClass mc = MyClass.fromMap(rd.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add .fromJson constructor in MyClass

Here it is :

```
MyClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
     organisationId= json['organisationId'],
     regionCode= json['regionCode'],
     defaultCulture= mapjson'defaultCulture']

  }
```

Then use it like this:

```
ServerResponse rd = response.data;
MyClass mc = MyClass.fromJson(rd.data);
```